# How to "unsuspend" a computer using command line

Tags: linux, suspend, systemctl

I'm writing a script to define what happens when I dock/undock the computer. I want it to suspend when I undock the computer while the lid is closed and "unsuspend" when I dock it back. Is there any way I could do this in a bash script?

Answer (score 3):

If a computer is suspended, it cannot run any script. So waking up via bash is impossible.

*systemctl suspend* is the console command to suspend your computer.

Dock and undock scripts can be triggered via udev, cf. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts#Dock_and_Undock_Scripts.

Using lid open and close events is described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/525995/catch-lid-close-and-open-events

Comment: Ok. But that makes me wonder how the "open the lid" event is handled by the kernel..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot unsuspend a computer by running any script if it's suspended as it will not execute any script.